# How can I set up insta-sneak-kill and insta-death?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, mods

I want to play a character where **all** my sneak bow attacks deal an insane amount of damage and I take an insane amount of damage from enemies.

Currently my plan is to play on Legendary difficulty so that everything will most likely kill me instantly. I thought about using the console to increase my damage multiplier with `attackdamagemult` but I want just my sneak attacks to deal a ton of damage.

Most mods I've found affect all damage instead of just sneak damage.

Ideally I want to achieve this without any mods but I'm not opposed to using mods.

Comment: The problem with playing in Legendary is not only does it make you super easy to kill, IIRC it also makes the enemies super hard to kill.  Legendary difficulty might make it impossible to 1 shot enemies without modding in a god item.

Comment: @GeneralMike Can't I just set `attackdamagemult` to a really really high number? I haven't actually tried any of this.

Comment: Perhaps - I don't use the console commands much, so there could be something you could use there to make your attacks very strong.  I just felt like it should be pointed out that Legendary mode makes enemies harder to kill.  You could probably also go the other way - play on a super easy difficulty level and use commands to fix your max hp at 1, assuming there is a command for that.

Comment: I did consider that option but I decided against it because it would have the side effect of me dying from walking into a cabbage. I want to preserve regular damage from non-enemy sources.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
SetAV.Player critchance 100
```

[Source](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Console_Commands_(Skyrim)/ActorValues)

This sets your critical hit chance to 100%, which usually is enough for one hit kills. Since critical hits seem to only happen while you're sneaking, this might be a good workaround.

Other possible way is to unlock some critical hit perks from the Sneak skill tree.

Comment: If you unlock the Deadly Aim perk in the Stealth tree (two prerequisites) and all five levels of Overdraw, a bow does x6 damage, which isn't enough on its own. You'd need to temper the best bow you could get, perhaps with the Restoration potion exploit to make extreme Fortify Smithing potions. So it looks like your console command is pretty much required to get insane damage quickly.

Comment: My only complaint with the console command is it'll boost my damage overall instead of just sneaking. I pretty much want to be a destroyer when hidden and useless when detected, which makes me wonder about those scripted dragon fights..

Answer (score -1):

You also could Mark them for death then leave the vicinity, wait a while then sneak attack them! I one shotted the Ebony Warrior with this.